# Why is sorted documented as taking an iterable instead of a collection?

Tags: python

Is there some deeper meaning why Python's `sorted` is documented as taking an iterable (which may be infinite) instead of a collection (which is sized)?

For example, this will run forever:

```
# DO NOT RUN
import itertools

for item in sorted(itertools.count()):
    print(item)
```

I get that they'd want to allow `sorted` to work on a collection's iterable object instead of the collection itself, but isn't there a fundamental difference (perhaps to be reflected in `collections.abc`) between iterables that are guaranteed to raise a `StopIteration` and iterables that may be infinite?

Comment: good luck getting this answered. btw. no need to sort that - it comes out sorted ;o) - and essentialls even a `for a in itertools.count()` will not work out well for your program unless you break from it.

Comment: Isn't this a variation of the halting problem? How would `sorted` (or any other function for the matter) know that the iterable is finite or infinite without iterating over ir?

Comment: Fair point re: count already being sorted. I could have created an deterministically chaotic one to be cheeky. But the point is still that I would think `collections.abc` (which exists to provide some amount of duck type checking at instantiation time) might benefit from a distinction, unless I'm missing some more fundamental point.

Comment: Re: halting problem - it would know by being declared as such ahead of time (e.g. by using a different magic method `__finiter__` or a difference `collections.abc` class `SizedIterable`). I realize in typing this though that this isn't very Pythonic, where we ask forgiveness instead of permission.

Comment: @MikeRand fair enough, I guess, but that would require a fundamental non-backwards-compatible change to the language code which I don't see happening in the near future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is documented as such because it does not make use of `__len__` for working, although you are right in that it should ask for a finite `Iterable` for being meaningful. Note that an `Iterable` can be finite and yet not support `__len__`, contrarily to `Collection`. Python does not make an explicit distinction between *finite* and *indefinite* `Iterable`s.

Consider the following **toy** example:

```
x = iter(range(10, 0, -1))

len(x)
# TypeError: object of type 'range_iterator' has no len()

# BUT
y = sorted(x)
print(y)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Good point re: there being a distinction between being `Sized` with `__len__` and being guaranteed to be finite. I hadn't thought about that. All in all seems like a good decision on their part: trust the programmer not to be an idiot.

Answer (score 3):

It's documented as taking an iterable because it takes an iterable. It's not restricted to collections. You can sort a `map` iterator with `sorted` just fine, as long as it's finite.

Sure, the iterable has to be finite, but that's not a type distinction. Different instances of the same iterable class may be finite or infinite. For example, some generators are finite, and some generators are infinite. You couldn't meaningfully define an ABC for "finite iterable".

The documentation could be more explicit about the finiteness requirement, but it could also be more explicit about plenty of other things, like the requirement that `<` is a strict weak ordering over the input elements or the `key` return values.

Comment: A map adheres to the collection interface. A finite iterable is easy: `__len__` and `__iter__`, but not `__contains__`.

Comment: "You can sort a `map` iterator with `sorted` just fine" unless `map` was given an infinite iterator to begin with

Comment: @MikeRand: No it doesn't. Maybe you're thinking of dicts?

Comment: @MikeRand That is not true. `len(map(...))` throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: @MikeRand: Finite iterables don't need a `__len__`.

Comment: Apologies, you're right. @DeepSpace's comment captures the real issue ... the `map` iterator would just inherit its finite/infinite nature from the iterable over which you were mapping.